# Parse local HTML file

Tags: html, powershell

I can use PowerShell to parse an HTML page

```sh
PS > $foo = Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com

PS > $foo.Links.Count
1
```

However if I download the page

```sh
PS > Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile example.htm http://example.com
```

and then try to parse the downloaded page it gives unexpected result

```sh
PS > $foo = Invoke-WebRequest file://$pwd/example.htm

PS > $foo.Links.Count
0
```

How can I parse the local downloaded page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the file with a
[web server](http://github.com/cesanta/mongoose)
to get around the dumb limitation of Invoke-WebRequest

```sh
PS > $foo = Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:8080/example.htm

PS > $foo.Links.Count
1
```

Note this will work even with no connection, example

```
PS > Invoke-WebRequest http://example.com
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote name could not be resolved: 'example.com'
```

Answer (score 27):

It appears that `Invoke-WebRequest` loads `file` protocol URIs just fine, but fails to parse them even in PowerShell 4.0 (where it is officially supported).

An alternative that does not require setting up a website would be to load and parse HTML directly into MSHTML.

```
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile";
$source = Get-Content -Path "file.html" -Raw;
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source);

$html.links.length;
```

Note that when I tested this, a single

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

header prevented my HTML from parsing and I have no idea why -- the document had similar XHTML-style headers and MSHTML had no issues with those.

Comment: Upvote for the first sentence. I was trying hundreds of time seeing Invoke-WebRequest methods hang for no reason. Now Invoke-RestMethod and putting it like you suggested saved me ;]

Comment: Very handy, thanks. As for the `IE=edge` issue: from what I understand, it forces parsing by the most recent standards, so perhaps your actual document content wasn't standards-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Use file-link format

```
$foo = Invoke-WebRequest "file://<path-to-file>"
```

**Fix my mistake**

If html is valid xml then you can use [select-xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-4.0):

```
[xml]$html = Get-Content '<path_to_html_file>'
Select-Xml $html -XPath '//a' | foreach {$_.node}
```

Comment: The querent specifically said that this doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Please see the 3rd forward slash in link format as opposed to the double-slash format used by the OP

Comment: @F.I.V - Good catch! I'm not sure how I missed that!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I meant that with three slashes /// it works!. This makes this answer different from what has been claimed not working in the OP text. So the former version of this text was correct and working (for me) with three forward slashes after file and colon