# Using Matches in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am fairly new with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) and would like some assistance.  I am pulling file locations from a CSV file, searching those files for links. Capturing the links and would like to export to a new CSV file with the matches in one column and the file they were found in another.

I am having trouble arranging my results.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far.

```
$csv = Import-csv "C:\Users\n609078\Desktop\testing_aaron\find_test.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {

$path = $_.path

    Select-String $path -pattern '<a href="(.*?)".*?>.*?</a>' -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value} 

}
```

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. What is the content/headers of `c:\find_test.csv`? If it's a proper csv file use `Import-csv` to read it into a variable.

Comment: Thanks ,my csv doesn't have headers.  It's just one column consisting of different file locations to html files that I would like to search for links.

Comment: Not really a csv then..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows PowerShell parse HTML local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494140/windows-powershell-parse-html-local-file)

Comment: I have revised my code and added a header "path" to my csv.  I'm pulling the links but still not sure how to export to new CSV.  Update in original code above