# Discrepency between getElementById and getElementsByName in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dom

I'm having a problem with Powershell and MSHTML: getElementById and getElementsByTagName are giving me different results.

I have this HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Moo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <ul id="a">
            <li>Bob
            <li>Cat
            <li>Fish
        </ul>
        <ul id="b">
            <li>Bob
            <li>Dog
            <li>Cow
        </ul>
        <div id="x">
            <b>What's the problem? Don't you <i>like soup</b> like this?</i>.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes, it's purposely meant to be badly nested as I'm playing with ideas (and testing for limitations) at the moment.

I'm loading this file into Powershell with MSHTML by doing (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989452/130352 ):

```
$html = new-object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$source = get-content -path $htmlFileName -raw
$html.IHtmlDocument2_write($source)
```

If I now do:

```
$d = $html.getElementById("x")
$d.TagName
```

I get the expected output (`DIV`). However if I do:

```
$d = $html.getElementsByTagName("div")
$d[0].TagName
```

I get no output. `$d.length` returns 1. `$d[0] | ft` spits out all the properties and values without a problem. But accessing properties from $d[0] directly doesn't return anything (i.e., asking for innerText, outerHtml, etc return no data, whilst finding the element by ID (i.e., with `getElementById`) has no problem and I can access the properties.

Similarly, if I assign to a variable (i.e., `$z = $d[0]`), and then work directly on $z, I get the same issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question.

Couldn't explain *exactly* what's happening, but it seems that

```
$d = $html.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

returns a collection that PowerShell doesn't know how to natively manipulate.

If you attempt to select some (or all) of the properties, then the variable does get fully populated:

```
($d | select *)[0].tagname
```

If using the `getElementsByTagName` method, you could do

```
$d = $html.getElementsByTagName("div") | select *
$d[0].tagname
```

It seems that piping the `ComObject` to the `Select-Object` causes it to be cast as a PowerShell `PSCustomObject` which you're then able to work with:

```
[PS]> ($html.getelementsbytagname("div") | select *).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object


[PS]> ($html.getelementsbytagname("div")).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    __ComObject                              System.MarshalByRefObject
```

Not 100% sure this "answers" the question, as I can't fully explain the behaviour, but it's a viable workaround at the least

Comment: Ah - that's interesting. I've just tried `$d | %{ $_.tagname }` for the `...bytagname` collection and this iterates happily, and I get the tagname. So yes, it's related to the collection. `GetElementsByTagName` returns an `IXMLDOMNodeList`. I'm guessing this can't actually be indexed into (*heads off to MSDN*).

Comment: Yep, that's it. IXMLDOMNodeList has an `item` method to access it's parts, so `$d.Item(0)` gets an individual item. Or turn into an array with `$arr = $d | %{ $_ }` (which I think is another way of doing your pipe into `select *`) and use `$arr[0]`. Or in other words, I should have RTFM.

Comment: Haha, good to know all the same! Makes sense thinking about it, a node list isn't an array so one would need to call a method to iterate to a particular position rather than directly addressing.