# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest not returning HtmlWebResponseObject

Tags: powershell

I'm using Invoke-WebRequest on a network HTML file. It returns WebResponseObject.
I would like for it to be a HtmlWebResponseObject. Not sure what it has against my local html file.

Any ideas?

Comment: WebResponseObject is the base class for HtmlWebResponseObject, does it just need to be down cast?

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of [Parse local HTML file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24977233/932282)

Comment: Another victim here of powershell's inscrutable behaviour. Invoke-WebRequest will return  a WebResponseObject, or maybe BasicHtmlWebResponseObject or perhaps HtmlWebResponseObject. Spin the wheel and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's suppose to be supported, but doesn't work :(.

This link helped me out

[Parse local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977233/parse-local-html-file)