# how to remove all image tags based on string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to remove the images from the HTML of a few hundred pages from a folder. The common string is "/stream/image.axd". I have tried using RegEx but I cannot seem to figure out how to get to the start and end parts of the tags.

An example would look like the below.

The new gears look like `<img src="/stream/image.axd?picture=planetary.gif" width="600" height="237">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you shouldn't parse html using regular expressions, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2412846). If you still want to do it, you can use something like

```
Get-Content 'file.html' | ForEach{$_ -replace '<.*/stream/image\.axd.*?>'}
```

More advanced, you can use the method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989452/2412846) in order to set up a .NET-parsed version of a local html file:

```
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile";
$source = Get-Content -Path "file.html" -Raw;
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source);
```

Once you have it you can identify the images by tag name and then use the method `removeNode` in order to remove the image-tags.

Comment: It looks like -replace '<.*/stream/image\.axd.*>' removes all text everywhere. As in when it finds paragraphs that have the image string they get deleted. Any suggestions? REGEX befuddles me.

Comment: @JohnM.: my fault. What you need is a non-greedy pattern matching (accomplished by another `?` sign, I'll edit).