# Powershell parsing local HTML file

Tags: powershell

Im trying to iterate through multiple HTML files in multiple computers.

**My code is below:**

```
ForEach ($system in (Get-Content C:\temp\computers.txt)) {

    $folder = "\\$system\c`$\ProgramData\Autodesk\AdLM\"
    Get-ChildItem $folder *.html  |
    Foreach-Object {
        $c = $_.BaseName
        $html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
        $HTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($(Get-content $_.Name -Raw ))
        $para1 = $HTML.getElementById('para1') | % InnerText
        Add-Content -path c:\temp\results.csv "$c,$system,$para1"
    }
 }
```

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
New-Object : Cannot find parameter Raw
```

Comment: @BryceMcDonald - The `New-Object` cmdlet is a built-in PowerShell cmdlet. The querent should look at https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Powershell-Tip-Parsing-49eb8810 for handling HTML files using the Document Object Model.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm aware of the cmdlet, for some reason I couldn't see where he had it in his code but I do now. I'll keep drinking this coffee and hope it helps.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977233/parse-local-html-file

Comment: @Ankh2054 What is _"localfiée"_?

Comment: let me check again as I've realised I'm using powershell2 which does not have Raw parameter.

Comment: Powershell 2 is really buggy with the HTMLFile com object - you may want to try using an internet explorer com object @Ankh2054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Internet Explorer COM object to do what you'd like the HTMLFile COM object to do.  HTMLFile isn't working 100% in all versions of Powershell, so this is a viable alternative.

```
ForEach ($system in (Get-Content C:\temp\computers.txt)) {
  $folder = "\\$system\c`$\ProgramData\Autodesk\AdLM\"
  Get-ChildItem $folder *.html  |
  ForEach-Object {
    $c = $_.BaseName
    $ie=New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
    $ie.Navigate("$_")
    while ($ie.busy -eq $true) {
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
    $doc=$ie.Document
    $elements=$doc.GetElementByID('para1')
    $elements.innerText | ForEach-Object { Add-Content -path c:\temp\results.csv "$c,$system,$para1" }
  }
}
```