# Assign the text between Bold tags to a variable

Tags: powershell

Having assigned a line of HTML to a variable how can I most efficiently extract the text between the Bold tags and assign that text to a second variable? I.E.:

```
<TR><TD width="30%" colSpan=2><B>Cyan Cartridge</B></TD> <TD width="25%"> <TABLE borderColor=#000000 cellSpacing=0 width="100%" border=1>
```

I want to assign "Cyan Cartridge" to $x.

Comment: Cast it to `[xml]` and use an accessor to get at it.

Comment: When casting to [xml] a number of "unexpected token" errors pop up.  For instance in colSpan=2, the number 2 is an unexpected token.  The # generates "unexpected token"  So I don't think this will work for me.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 will that work if the whole documnt is not all valid xml? For instance the snipped in the post uses `colSpan=2` without quotation marks - valid HTML, but not XML

Comment: @Martin23mm are you trying to extract across small portions of an HTML document or all instance of text inside bold tags across an entire document?

Comment: @NextInLine - small portions of an HTML document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex - although be cautious as regex and html can be a bit of a flaky combo.

```
$x = '<TR><TD width="30%" colSpan=2><B>Cyan Cartridge</B></TD> <TD width="25%"> <TABLE borderColor=#000000 cellSpacing=0 width="100%" border=1>'
$y = $x | select-string -pattern "(?<=<B>|b>)(.|\n)*?(?=<\/B|b)" | % {$_.matches} | % {$_.Value}
$y
```

**Outputs**

> Cyan Cartridge

For an explanation of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/Ub7LsG/1

Answer (score 1):

The preferred option is to use powershell's HTML parsing as listed on [Parse local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977233/parse-local-html-file).

However, if that doesn't work (the answers suggest it has issues), your next best option is regular expressions:

```
$matches = Select-String '(?<=<B>).+?(?=</B>)'
$matches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

`Select-String` can be run on a local file a string representing the contents of a file. It is also case-insensitive by default, so it will find both `<b>` and `<B>`.

In general, regular expressions are a bad way to parse HTML - use them only for one-time or personal scripts, not something that you need to depend on not breaking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$source = '<TR><TD width="30%" colSpan=2><B>Cyan Cartridge</B></TD> <TD width="25%"> <TABLE borderColor=#000000 cellSpacing=0 width="100%" border=1>'
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source)

foreach($node in $html.body.childNodes)
{
    if($node.tagname -eq "b")
    {
        $node.innerHTML = "test"
    }

}
```

something along these lines should work, though my final html values looked a little off, it seemed to correctly update the value between the B tags. I might have been looking at the wrong property for the final body.